# Stimulus controller not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, stimulus-rails

I'm getting this message on my console and I cannot find a solution:

`Failed to register controller: search (controllers/search_controller) TypeError: The 'stimulus' specifier was a simple specifier, but it has not been remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with './', '../', or '/'.`

I'm using `rails 7.0.2` and `importmap.rb` to install my JS.

I tried rerouting the `import.map` and redoing the stimulus documentation manual installing and it hadn't worked.

Comment: Apparently you are not importing controller(or stimulus) properly. Can you provide the code in which you do it?

Comment: This is my importmap:

pin_all_from 'app/javascript/controllers', under: 'controllers'
pin '@hotwired/turbo-rails', to: 'turbo.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus', to: 'stimulus.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus-loading', to: 'stimulus-loading.js', preload: true
pin 'application', preload: true
pin 'bootstrap', to: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.11.2/dist/esm/index.js"

Comment: This is my application controller:

import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're importing from `stimulus` in your `search_controller.js`. You need to change all references from `stimulus` to `@hotwired/stimulus`:

```js
// import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem!

Comment: @ArthurFinamore - it's always good to upvote an answer that answers your question. This helps people find this answer easier in the future. A comment is great but an upvote is what the Stack overflow site uses to rank things.

Comment: I tried upvoting, but it says I need a higher reputation to do it.